# Making custom uitableviewcell in a uitableview on top of a cocos2d layer

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone

First here is the code showing the uiviewcontroller which contain the uitableview:

```
//View Controller with navigation bar
InAppPurchaseViewController *purchaseViewController = [[InAppPurchaseViewController alloc] init];
purchaseViewController.title = @"Liste de packs";
purchaseViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissViewController:)] autorelease];

//Creation de la navigation bar et release du viewcontroller
UINavigationController *navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:purchaseViewController] autorelease];
[purchaseViewController release];

container = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[container setView:[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView]];
[container setModalTransitionStyle: UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
[container presentModalViewController: navController animated: YES];
```

here is my uitableviewcell:

InAppPurchaseCell.h

```
@interface InAppPurchaseCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *ImageThumbnail;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *BuyButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *TitleLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *PriceLabel;
@end
```

InAppPurchaseCell.m

```
@implementation InAppPurchaseCell
@synthesize PriceLabel;
@synthesize TitleLabel;
@synthesize BuyButton;
@synthesize ImageThumbnail;

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];  
}
@end
```

InAppPurchaseCell.xib

All the iboutlet are linked correctly

And :

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifierCasual = @"ShopCell";
    InAppPurchaseCell *cell = (InAppPurchaseCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierCasual];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = (InAppPurchaseCell*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"InAppPurchaseCell" owner:nil options:nil]lastObject];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    }
    Packages *packages = [PackagesParser loadData];
    Package *package = [packages.Packages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.ImageThumbnail.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-Small.png"];
    cell.PriceLabel.text = @"0,75$";
    cell.TitleLabel.text = package.Name; 

    return cell;
}
```

What's hapenning when the table pop up :

```
2012-07-13 13:56:55.378 Testing[1276:1c103] *** Terminating app due to uncaught 
exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0xa10da00> 
setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ImageThumbnail.'
```

At this line :

```
cell = (InAppPurchaseCell*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"InAppPurchaseCell" owner:nil options:nil]lastObject];
```

Does someone has an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may help you

```
InAppPurchaseCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell==nil) {     
   cell=[[InAppPurchaseCell alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)     
   reuseIdentifier:@"ShopCell"];
}
```

Comment: initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier: is deprecated i think but i'll try this method... Ok i didn't remember but i already tried initWithFrame: With this method i don't get errors the table is created, with the right amount of rows BUT the rows are empty:
    cell.PriceLabel.text is nil right after cell.PriceLabel.text = @"0,75$"; which is not normal =(

Comment: in inAppCell.h add your label price label lable programtically at      - (id) initWithFrame: (CGRect) frame reuseIdentifier: (NSString *) aReuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithFrame: frame reuseIdentifier: aReuseIdentifier];
    if(self)
    {     self.priceLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 115, 220, 21)];
       self.contentview addsubview:self.priceLabel
} try like this

Comment: Well it's works for the labels but : Not for the buttons and this solution doesn't since really clean >.<

Comment: Try to add everything pragmatically like label. I think this approach may work fine. But for the buttons you need to specify the tags properly to identify which button of Cell is clicked. This needs to assign at time of cell creation.

Comment: The thing is i have already done this kind of thing (uitableview + uitableviewcustomcell) in another project. And it works just fine with the nib file. When the cell is created the iboutlet should be allocated if they are linked properly i am right ?

Comment: Yah. But I never tried that approach in my projects. I used to create custom cells using code only to avoid the confusion of cell Nib connection. I used to take place holder view on top to add the labels,buttons, images. Finally i used add the place holder view to the content view of cell.